# Download Texture in Unity3d giving InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-maps

I'm trying to use google maps texture in my unity project. But am facing issues in the same.

I checked the logged url for the call, and when I use it in the browser, it works fine. I'm trying to load that texture into a cube.

Here is the code am using. Can someone pls guide me on what am I doing wrong and how to correct the same? Pls let me know if you need more details.

### Approach 1 - Using WWW approach:

```
string googleStaticMapsURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=42.49414,-83.40547&size=1024x1024&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&markers=size:mid|color:orange|label:abc|44.49414,-83.40547";

WWW req = new WWW(googleStaticMapsURL);

cubeObject.SetActive (true);

// Create a texture in DXT1 format
cubeObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = 
                new Texture2D(size, size, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);

while (!req.isDone) {
    Debug.Log ("req.isdone is false");
    yield return 0;
}

if (req.error == null) {
    Debug.Log ("Response form Google maps texture service:: ");
    req.LoadImageIntoTexture ((Texture2D)cubeObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture);
}  else {
    Debug.Log ("Google maps.. Req.error is:: " + req.error);
}
```

Error : Unsupported url.

I read in some posts that WWW does not work well in iOS and to try UnityWebRequest instead. So I modified the code as below.

### Approach 2 - Using UnityWebRequest approach:

```
string googleStaticMapsURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=42.49414,-83.40547&size=1024x1024&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&markers=size:mid|color:orange|label:abc|44.49414,-83.40547";

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(googleStaticMapsURL);
DownloadHandlerTexture textD = new DownloadHandlerTexture ();
www.downloadHandler = textD;

yield return www.Send();

if (www.isError) {
    Debug.Log ("Error in Google maps web service::" + www.error);
}  else {
    Debug.Log ("Time1:: " + Time.time + ".. isDone::" + www.isDone);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); //wait for 3 secs
    Debug.Log ("Time2:: " + Time.time + ".. isDone::" + www.isDone);
    while (!www.isDone) {
        Debug.Log ("www.isdone is false");
    }
    // Show results as text
    //sphereObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = 
    //                          new Texture2D(size, size, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
    Debug.Log("Setting Texture!!");
    Debug.Log("Response form Google maps texture service:: "+ textD.texture.height);
    cubeObject.SetActive (true);
    //cubeObject.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive (true);
    cubeObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = textD.texture;
}
```

**Error : InvalidOperationException: Texture has not yet finished downloading**

But I can see www.isDone printing as True. Can you pls help me in getting this fixed?

Also, am using https version of the google maps url, but still I see the below warning in the console. The printed url shows https protocol only.

**You are using download over http. Currently unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.**

Comment: Hi Friends, can you pls let me know why was it downvoted? If you feel there is need for more information, pls let me know.

Comment: @Hristo, I have edited my question. Would you mind taking a look at it again, and help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it is not working with you, just attached this script to cube object and it works fine:

```
public class TextureLoader : MonoBehaviour 
{

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        string path = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=42.49414,-83.40547&size=1024x1024&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&markers=size:mid|color:orange|label:abc|44.49414,-83.40547";
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(path);
        DownloadHandlerTexture textD = new DownloadHandlerTexture ();
        www.downloadHandler = textD;

        yield return www.Send();

        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            yield return www;
        }

        if (www.isError) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Error in Google maps web service::" + www.error);
        }  
        else 
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = textD.texture;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your update. I tried running your code as well, but I get the same issue 'InvalidOperationException: Texture has not yet finished downloading' when trying to run in the device (iPhone 6, iOS 10.3), but runs fine in Unity play mode. Could this be some problem in iOS? Any idea how to address it?